# Automapper not mapping IEnumerable<T> to IEnumerable<T> in Viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have the following classes defined;

```
Data.Models.Lists.List

Infrastructure.Models.Lists.List
```

Both contain the following fields;

```
public int Id { get; set; }

public string Description { get; set; }
```

I also have this View Model defined;

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
     public IEnumerable<Infrastructure.Models.Lists.List> Lists { get; set; }
}
```

Within my Automapper configuration, I am simply doing the following;

```
cfg.CreateMap< Data.Models.Lists.List, Infrastructure.Models.Lists.List>()
```

Which I thought would be enough, but I also added this;

```
cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<List>,Models.Lists.IndexViewModel>();
```

However, when I attempt to map the items in my controller;

```
var items = ListsService.GetLists(CurrentPrincipal.Id);

var model = Mapper.Map<IndexViewModel>(items);
```

model.Lists is always null, although items has 22. What else needs to be added in order to get this mapping working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AutoMapper does automatic mapping of the properties of the two types with the same name.

In order to map the whole source object to a target object property as in your case, you have to specify that explicitly:

```
cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Data.Models.Lists.List>, Models.Lists.IndexViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Lists, m => m.MapFrom(src => src));
```

Comment: I think that's what I am looking for. Unable to test this until the morning, but looks the ticket

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are mapping your items to the instance of the viewmodel directly, not it's `Lists` property. Your first mapping config is fine, the second one you don't need.

```
var model = new IndexViewModel()
{
    Lists = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Infrastructure.Models.Lists.List>>(items)
};
```

Comment: I see, makes sense when you point it out! I really wanted to keep all the mapping logic in a single place, it looks like the code above would sit in the controller. I assume there would be a way to do this from the mappings. Will take a further looks in the morning. Thanks